# Get pixel values from image: Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have a simple green fluorescent image. I want to find the total number of pixels that are above a specific value using MATLAB. I don't know where the pixel values are stored in an image.

Here is the green fluorescent image. I want to know which percentage of the pixels have value of more than a specific threshold. For example in this image, if the pixel value in the cells are around X, then I want to find the total number of pixels that are above X.

[image]

Comment: Show us the image...

Comment: I posted the image below as an answer. Thanks

Comment: As your image is colour, you have three components - Red, Green and Blue. Do you want to know how many pixels are above a threshold in the Red or the Green or the Blue channel or how many are above a threshold in all three channels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read a *colored* image using [`imread`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html#outputarg_A), you get a 3D matrix in which the first two indices are the image coordinates; (row, columns); and the last index represents the color channels. For the typical use case of an RGB image, the color channels are:

```
1 = red
2 = green
3 = blue.
```

Other possibilities are grayscale, CMYK and indexed images. Please check the [official documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html#outputarg_A) for more information.